# Inserting into database filling only 2 row

Tags: java, mysql

Hello I want to insert values into my database where the Database table has 3 rows

id - item - date

here I want to fill the Item and the Date row because the ID is a Auto_increment field where it goes id++ for each record. but Now I don't know how my query should be like in Java because its much different then i'm used to be ( in PHP )

I think this is the relevant code

```
st = con.createStatement();
String query = "INSERT INTO toDoList " + "VALUES ('" + value + "', 'CURDATE()')";
st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Can someone telle me what to fill in for the first record? I tried just empty quotes but that results in a error..

Answer (score 2):

As id is auto-increment, you don't need to give any value, just list all the columns minus your id column in your query.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO toDoList(item, date) " + "VALUES ('" + value + "', 'CURDATE()')";
```

I see that you are new to java developement, i would recommend you to use [**preparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than simple statement to execute SQL queries using JDBC in order to prevent from SQL Injection

Example:

```
String query="INSERT INTO toDoList(item, date) VALUES (?,?)";";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(youritemval);
st.setDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I would recommend using PreparedStatement and binding variables rather than concatenating a String this way.  And a column named DATE is not very self-describing.  Using keywords for table and column names is asking for trouble.  I'd call it ITEM_INSERTION_DATE.

Comment: how can I use CURDATE() in a prepared statement? and st.setString(); wants 2 values what should the other value be?

Comment: @Reshad you can always get CURDATE() in java, you don't really need SQL's CURDATE(), check my edit :)

Comment: But that is like more code to write.. so it should be easier right?

Comment: @Reshad that's how you get curdate in java, well, you could always usesimple statement as you are using, but as said it would lead you to sql injection

Comment: I am getting error with your solution of inserting in Java way.. it sees it as a string?

Comment: Update the question with your new code. It's probably very simple error:)

Answer (score 1):

If your values are not for all column then you have to define column name while inserting data.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO toDoList(item,date) " + "VALUES ('" + value + "', 'CURDATE()')";
```